# Can I reference on an alias in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, alias

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT
ARUTORZS.ARUKOD,
ARUTORZS.ARUNEV,
(SELECT SUM(MENNYISEG)
  FROM ((((STOREIS.KESZLET
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.THELY ON
  THELY.TH=KESZLET.TH)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.ZONA ON
  ZONA.ZONAKOD=THELY.ZONA)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.ARUTELEP ON
  ARUTELEP.TH_KOD='P' AND
  ARUTELEP.ARUKOD=KESZLET.ARUKOD)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.RAKTAR ON
  RAKTAR.RAKTAR=KESZLET.RKOD)
  WHERE KESZLET.ARUKOD=ARUTORZS.ARUKOD ) AS keszlet,
ARUTELEP.RKOD,
ARUTELEP.ZONA_KOMISSIOS,
ARUTORZS.GYARTO_KOD,
UGYFEL.ORACLE_KOD,
UGYFEL.SZAML_NEV,
ARUTORZS.SULY,
**ARUTORZS.SULY*keszlet/1000 AS SULYKG,**
ARUTORZS.REL_LEJ,
ARUTORZS.GYUJTO,
ARUTORZS.RAKLAP_MENNY
FROM ((STOREIS.ARUTORZS
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.ARUTELEP ON
ARUTELEP.TH_KOD='P' AND
ARUTELEP.ARUKOD=ARUTORZS.ARUKOD)
LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.UGYFEL ON
UGYFEL.UGYF_KOD=ARUTORZS.GYARTO_KOD)
WHERE ARUTELEP.RKOD>=100 AND ARUTELEP.RKOD<=199
```

The keszlet subquery works, but Ican't reference on its result in another column. How can I reference on the result of the keszlet subquery? I want to multiply it in another column.

Comment: Wrap the qeury up as a _derived table_.

Answer (score 1):

Use a table expression.

For example:

```
select 
  x.*,
  c * m as r
from (
  select
    a,
    (select max(b) from t) as m,
    c
  from t
) x
```

The table expression produces a "named column" `m` that you can use in the main query in the expression `c * m`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your result from your subquery, but u have to use it as a table subquery.

> Description
>
> With table subqueries, the outer query treats the result of the
> subquery as a table. You can only use these in the FROM clause.

So, your subquery goes after the `FROM` clause and you can make a new join like this:

```
SELECT your_result_value * --do what you want...

FROM 

(SELECT SUM(MENNYISEG) as YOUR_RESULT_VALUE, PK --your_primary_key
  FROM ((((STOREIS.KESZLET
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.THELY ON
  THELY.TH=KESZLET.TH)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.ZONA ON
  ZONA.ZONAKOD=THELY.ZONA)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.ARUTELEP ON
  ARUTELEP.TH_KOD='P' AND
  ARUTELEP.ARUKOD=KESZLET.ARUKOD)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN STOREIS.RAKTAR ON
  RAKTAR.RAKTAR=KESZLET.RKOD)
  WHERE KESZLET.ARUKOD=ARUTORZS.ARUKOD ) keszlet

  JOIN "your_tables" ON keszlet.PK = "another_PK"
    --and so on...
```